# SSRS: Position Matrix Cell at Intermediate Column Grouping Level, and also inside a Row Group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have an SSRS matrix that has one level of row groups and two levels of column groups.  I have a textbox that is positioned inside one of the column groups, and outside of the other one, which is what I want.  But I also want this textbox to be positioned inside of a row group.

Basically, I would like #1 in the screenshot below to have a row group associated with it so that #2 is inside that row group.

[image: Screenshot - SSRS Grouping Issue]

My goal is to conditionally set the row-visibility for the first row.  But "row visibility..." is greyed out.  As far as I can tell, the way to get the option is to make sure it's inside of a row group.

The reason I want to set visibility is because the user has the option to show or hide charts, and separately to show or hide data.  If the user selects both charts and data, then I don't need the first row because the label for the data can describe the chart as well.  But if the user only selects charts, then I need that first row.

If there's another approach outside of minimizing the row height, I'm all ears.
 Though I'm still interested in whether this puzzle is even solvable, and if not, why not.

---

#### Steps to Repeat

A version of this problem can be repeated as follows:

- Insert a new matrix in a report
- Just fill in dummy values, such as a blank space, into the "RowGroup1" and "ColumnGroup" "Group On" expressions.
- Add a parent group to the column group, and similarly just give it a dummy grouping expression.
- Delete the second row of the matrix, via "Delete Rows Only"

You now have a matrix with the same problem.  Namely, get the second cell of the first row, to be inside of a row grouping.